# How to display special characters in Imperavi Redactor?

Tags: special-characters, redactor

I'd like to find an easy way to insert special characters in Imperavi's redactor.

In Windows, users can insert a Greek letter such as ß with the keyboard shortcut Alt+225.

But is there a way to have a more user-friendly feature in Redactor to insert such characters, perhaps through a dedicated menu?

Comment: Just for future reference, ß is not the Greek letter beta; it's an "S sharp," a ligature used in German.

Comment: Thanks for this distinction: β/ß --> Greek beta/German Eszett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a way with a custom dropdown button :

```
buttonsCustom: {
            greek: {
                title: 'Special Characters', 
                dropdown: {
                    alpha: {title: '&alpha;',callback: function(obj){obj.insertHtml('&alpha;');}},
                    beta: {title: '&beta;',callback: function(obj){obj.insertHtml('&beta;');}}
                }
            } 
        }
```